# How do I pass a URL as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically generated div tags. Each div tag contains several input fields and has an id which is a unique URL. I was trying to use the value present in the div by using button onclick. I tried using forms but was unable to pass the link as a parameter.

```
<div id="link">
    <input fields>
    <input fields>
    <button onclick="showInput(link)">Click me</button>
</div>
```

```
function showInput(id) {
    alert(id); // alerts "link" and not the actual value
    var container =  document.getElementById(id).value;    
    var value1= container.closest('#field1').val();
    var value2= container.closest('#field2').val();

    writeLinkScore(id,value1, value2);  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Container is a string and you are treating it as a jQuery object. That is your problem.

```
var container =  document.getElementById(id).value;  //String here    
var ddscore = container.closest('#field1').val();    //Act like it is jQuery here
```

and farther down in the code

```
writeLinkScore(id,field1, field2);  //where is field1 and field2 defined?
```

And you are not passing a string, you are passing in an object

```
<button onclick="showInput(link)">Click me</button>
```

---

```
<button onclick="showInput('link')">Click me</button>
```

and

```
function showInput(id) {
    var field1 = $('#field1').val();
    var field2 = $('#field2').val();
    writeLinkScore(id, field1, field2);  
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the errors

Comment: Still is wrong based on what I said.

Comment: It should be :
var field1 = container.find('#field1').val();
var field2 = container.find('#field2').val();

Comment: @epascarello thank you very much for corrections. But I'm still not able to send the get the actual link in the function.

Comment: What is the error in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little messy when you are using vanilla JS to select a DOM element and then use jQuery to traverse over it. Here are three steps you could do to refactor it a little bit:

1. Don't use onClick directly in HTML (definitely an anti-pattern). Bind an event handler to the button in a separate js file instead.
2. If you are going to use jQuery, select the element in jQuery way so that you will get a jQuery wrapped object with full fledged jQuery DOM traverse methods
3. If you are passing a unique url to a element, try use `data-*` attribute rather than pass to id directly. It would be weird if every time you want to get the element by id, you'll have to key in a long url.

An this is an example you may try:

***HTML***

```
<div id="link1" class="linkDiv" data-link="/your/url/slug">
  <input id="field1">
  <input id="field2">
  <button class="linkBtn">Click me</button>
</div>
```

***JS***

```
$(function() {      
  $('.linkBtn').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var link = $this.closest('.linkDiv').data('link');
    var field1 = $this.siblings('#field1').val();
    var field2 = $this.siblings('#field2').val();      

    writeLinkScore(link, field1, field2); 
  });

  function writeLinkScore() {
    // your write function
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the div is being dynamically generated, why not just pass the url as a paramater? For example if the url is "www.google.com"

I'm assuming what you currently have is:

```
<div id="www.google.com">
    <input fields>
    <input fields>
    <button onclick="showInput(www.google.com)">Click me</button>
</div>
```

why not do:

```
<div id="www.google.com">
    <input fields>
    <input fields>
    <button onclick="showInput('www.google.com')">Click me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: the link gets generated dynamically

Comment: Yes, the link gets generated dynamically, but it sounds like you are also generating the divs dynamically. The only way I can imagine they aren't being generated at the same time is if you have a variable in javascript.

    var urlName = "";

and then the div code ends up being

    <div id="urlName">
        <input fields>
        <input fields>
        <button onclick="showInput(urlName)">Click me</button>
    </div>

in which case the solution I proposed would still work, except you send the name of the variable as a string instead of the url itself.